# Privatelink latency impact

Tags: high-frequency, market-making, high-frequency-estimators, latency, low-latency

I am working with a team on a market making algorithm on Huobi. We are integrating our infrastructure in AWS and when you are a S tier you can get a privatelink which is about 10 to 50 ms faster than routing thru public networks. Are there any serious market makers here who have experienced the difference? It may be a decision to not go to Huobi as there is an 'unfair advantage' for groups or companies with less capital than the big boys. Or has someone integrated this latency disadvantage and how did it impacted their model?

So the two questions are:

- What is your experience when getting a privatelink connection at Huobi?
- What is the impact on your model when integrating the 'unfair disadvantage'?